# Friendly_id using value from belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, friendly-id, after-create

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :first_name, :use => :slugged

  has_one :professor
  after_create :create_professor

  def create_professor
    self.professor = Professor.create 
  end

end 

class Professor < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :first_name, :use => :slugged

  belongs_to :user
  def first_name
    user.first_name 
  end

end
```

At the time that `create_professor` is called and therefore the execution passes to the Professor model (`self.professor = Professor.create`), when it gets to try to create the **slug** in this method:

```
def first_name
  user.first_name 
end
```

I get an `undefined method first_name for nil:NilClass`, so it seems the Professor object doesn't know what is his associated user.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: try `self.professor.create` instead of `self.professor = Professor.create`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need:

```
  def create_professor
    self.professor = Professor.create 
  end
```

Since create_professor is created by your association.

Comment: I followed above procedure and i am getting error- Couldn't find Profile with id=xyz