# Set FriendlyID slug for relationship table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-url, friendly-id

I want to set slug from relationship table name How can I?

**For example**

```
Patient Table Info
Id
contact_id
...

Contact Table Info
FirstName - String
LastName - String
...

Patient Model Having below code

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :full_name, use: :slugged

def full_name
  contact.firstname + '' + contact.lastname
end
```

but slug is not working for full_name.  So help any one help me how can I generate slug with relationship table?

Comment: How is your relationship defined between Patient and Contact? Can you add the belongs_to / has_one (or whatever you have) from your model to the question? Thanks.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488700/friendly-id-using-value-from-belongs-to-association), it seems to be equivalent to yours.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is because of your full_name method.

Try changing...

```rb
def full_name
  contact.firstname + '' + contact.lastname
end
```

to...

```rb
def full_name
  [[self.contact.firstname, self.contact.lastname]]
end
```